# Memory leak with large number of SQL Logging strings in memory

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, memory-leaks

My app is running on Puma (2.4) cluster mode with 4 workers. 
Initially, they use less than 2GB RAM in total but grow continuously and finally take up to 7GB after 20 hours of running.

By using ObjectSpace, I find out that the number of string objects increases very fast, come from ~300k to 4-5 million objects in each worker.

Then I use the following script to group those strings by first 60 characters and perform counting:

```
counts = Hash.new(0) 
ObjectSpace.each_object do |o| 
  next unless (o.class == String) 
  counts[o[0,60]] += 1 
end
counts = counts.to_a.sort_by(&:last);
puts counts[-10..-1]
```

It turns out that most of those strings are SQL Logging from Active Record

```
ObjectSpace.count_objects
# result
{
     :TOTAL => 2439593,
      :FREE => 209200,
  :T_OBJECT => 65944,
   :T_CLASS => 11343,
  :T_MODULE => 2003,
   :T_FLOAT => 13,
  :T_STRING => 1821445,
  :T_REGEXP => 6570,
   :T_ARRAY => 157012,
    :T_HASH => 27477,
  :T_STRUCT => 1406,
  :T_BIGNUM => 1393,
    :T_FILE => 142,
    :T_DATA => 75081,
   :T_MATCH => 1334,
 :T_COMPLEX => 1,
:T_RATIONAL => 2809,
    :T_NODE => 51890,
  :T_ICLASS => 4530
}

# top 10 string
["PricingRule Exists: SELECT" , 74632]
[": SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `re" , 85454]
["CACHE: SELECT  `companies`" , 93045]
["PricingRule Load: SELECT  " , 114169]
["Page Load: SELECT  `pages`" , 140245]
[": SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `pa" , 182274]
["Customer Load: SELECT  `cu" , 191972]
["Company Load: SELECT  `com" , 253025]
["Page Load: SELECT `pages`." , 320267]
["DestinationCountry Load: S" , 413299]
```

I use Rails 4, Ruby 2, mysql2(v0.3.13) and set log level at warn, but those SQL string still be stored and keep increase in the memory.

Does anyone have any idea or experience with this problem? I'm very appreciate if you can help.

Thanks!

Comment: I have seen a similar issue with the EventMachine gem a few years ago. How good are you with C programming? We may need to get out hands dirty. Have a look at this: http://blog.nelhage.com/2013/03/tracking-an-eventmachine-leak/

Comment: If you follow along that article, you'll come to realize that 2 million string objects at 1k per object is only 2G. You mention 7G of memory usage. Either your strings are really long (in which case you are in luck since you have found the problem already) or the problem is deeper and you may need to delve into the C code.

Comment: @Chandranshu thank for your reply, it's 2 million string objects per worker, with 4 workers, they can take up to 8GB, which seem like the cause of the leak.

Comment: Oh Ok. Then you have almost nailed it. You just need to see which objects refer to these strings. The Strings are not getting garbage collected because of the owner object. If you try to do this on the bloated application, it'll be difficult. Just try analyzing 10minutes of Objectspace.

Comment: You may already know this but before you start analyzing the "10 minutes of Objectspace", make sure that you run the Garbage Collector manually once.

Comment: BTW, this can be an issue with Puma cluster mode. See [this ticket](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/342). As suggested by the owner there, can you add those lines to the config.ru and post the stats both here and there?

Comment: Thank @Chandranshu, I've already implemented some kind of "10 minutes of ObjectSpace" like you suggest, those SQL are most-used query in my app to fetch the current country, current customer, build page menu, etc. However, I don't know why those strings still be kept in the memory and not be cleaned by the GC.

Comment: You need to walk through your objects and check all string attributes of each object to find out which objects contains the references to these strings. I know it sounds tedious but that is the only way to proceed right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These string can from 'sql.active_record' event, the reason may you subscribe 
'sql.active_record' event and keep these string in your object so GB cannot release them.

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribed(callback, "sql.active_record") do
end
```

Make sure unsubscribe after using.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think about that. I use this to profile some of my SQL but never think this can be the root of my problem. Many thanks to you.